# redux saga yield all cancel other effect when one failed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I have issues with yield all in saga effect, I provide my sample code below

```
function* fetchData(item) {
  try {
    const data = yield call(request, url);
    yield put(fetchDataSuccess(data));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(fetchDataFailure(error));
    throw error;
  }
}

function* fetchSummary(action) {
  try {
      yield all(
        list.map(item=>
          call(fetchData, item)
        )
      );
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(
      enqueueSnackbar({
        message: "Has Error",
        options: { variant: "error" }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

The logic of it is that I want to call multiple requests (some success, and some failed).

Expected: If it has failed request, the error will be caught after yield all but those success requests still continue and it should dispatch action "fetchDataSuccess" after individual success request (Promise.all can do this)

Actual: If it has failed request, the error will be caught after yield all, and then saga immediately cancel all other "fetchData" call.

Can anyone help me to achieve this logic. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Actual" behavior that you are describing fits with what I am seeing in your code.  As soon as any error is thrown, we leave the `try` block and enter the `catch` block.

> When we `yield` an array of effects, the generator is blocked until all the effects are resolved or as soon as one is rejected (just like how `Promise.all` behaves). - [docs](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/RunningTasksInParallel.html)

If you want each `fetch` to execute then you would need to put the `try`/`catch` *inside* the `.map`.  You can either map to an array of `true`/`false` values or set a value on error. Or if you don't mind having multiple snackbars you could `put` `enqueueSnackbar` inside `fetchData` instead of in `fetchSummary`.

Here's one way to do it:

```
// modified to return either true or false
function* fetchData(item) {
  try {
    const data = yield call(request, item);
    yield put(fetchDataSuccess({ item, data }));
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(fetchDataFailure({ item, error }));
    return false;
  }
}

function* fetchSummary(action) {
  const results = yield all(
    action.payload.list.map((item) => call(fetchData, item))
  );
  // check if any of the results were false;
  const hasError = results.some((res) => !res);
  if (hasError) {
    yield put(
      enqueueSnackbar({
        message: "Has Error",
        options: { variant: "error" }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

[Code Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-saga-array-errors-epyy9?file=/src/store/saga.ts)

Comment: Yes, this is closely similar to Promise.all as the success Promise still run even if other has been failed. Just one thing different is that we can only toast a message when all promises are done, for Promise.all, the catch block will run right after the error was thrown while the other non-error Promises are still running